# How can I add methods that I often use to android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For example,

```
public void show_message(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I want this method add auto Activity.java when create new activity or java class.

I want to save different methods like this and include it in the my project quickly where it is needed.

Comment: you can make a custom class with those custom methods and import them in every project

Comment: It will not get generated on creating every activity. But what you can do is create an Activity called Base Activity and implement all these methods there. And then every new Activity you create extend that with BaseActivity. You can then access it in all activities

Comment: You can create a custom annotation, and you annotate the class with that annotation. It is hard though, as the annotation has to write to the class. YOu can check examples of annotations writing to the class by looking at [Lombok source](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok) and looking at the getter/setter annotation. It writes methods to a class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to make a **Common Utilities** class. Just copy and paste the class in whatever project you are using it. Just make its method access specifiers as **public staic** so that you can easily access it.
For e.g.

```
CommonUtilities.showToastMessage(String text);
```

Answer (score 7):

What you should do is create a `BaseActivity` and make your activity extend this `BaseActivity`. Add all the default methods in this activity so you can use them everywhere. You can refer [this](https://github.com/nieldeokar/AndroidMVPBase) Github project for reference. It uses MVP.

Here is direct link to [BaseActivity](https://github.com/nieldeokar/AndroidMVPBase/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/niel/mvpdemo/base/BaseActivity.java).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a config class and store all these small things in it. For example have a look at this :

```
public class Config {
    public Context context;
    public String sharedPrefsName;
    public String carTablesName, carsTableCarColumn, databaseName;
    public int databaseNewVersion, databaseOldVersion;
    public boolean showNotificationsToCustomer;
    public String customerNotificationState;
    public String userMobile;
    public SharedPreferences preferences;
    public String customerChatTableName;
    public String customerChatMessageColumn;
    public String customerChatSentByCustomerColumn;
    public String customerChatTimeColumn;
    public String loggedInUserId;
    public String loggedInUserName;
    public String customerChatSupportNotifyingUrl;

    public Config(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        customerChatSupportNotifyingUrl = "";
        customerChatTableName = "customerChat";
        customerChatMessageColumn = "customerMessage";
        customerChatTimeColumn = "sentOn";
        customerChatSentByCustomerColumn = "isSentByCustomer";
        sharedPrefsName = context.getString(R.string.shared_prefs_login_validator);
        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(sharedPrefsName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        customerNotificationState = context.getString(R.string.customer_notification_state);
        showNotificationsToCustomer = preferences.getBoolean(customerNotificationState, true);
        carTablesName = context.getString(R.string.user_car_table);
        carsTableCarColumn = context.getString(R.string.user_car_table_car_column);
        databaseName = context.getString(R.string.user_db);
        databaseNewVersion = 3;
        databaseOldVersion = 1;
        loggedInUserId = preferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.user_db), "");
        userMobile = preferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.user_mobile), "");
        loggedInUserName = preferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.user_name), "");
    }
}
```

I've placed all the constants in a single file so you need not look at them always. If your app grows in size this would be extremely useful.

For using a progress dialog I use a class like this :

```
public class MyProgressDialog extends ProgressDialog {
    String title, message;

    public MyProgressDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
        super(context);
        if (!title.equals("")) this.setTitle(title);
        this.setMessage(message);
        this.setCancelable(false);
        this.setIndeterminate(false);
    }
}
```

This is nothing but a single class that extends ProgressDialog.So you can aquire all the functionalities of the progress dialog class.

Similarly for toast you could do the same. If you want them to appear when the activity gets created simply keep this:

```
MyProgressDialog dialog=new MyProgressDialog(this,"title","message");
dialog.show();
```

in your activity's onCreate() method. You can do the same for toast too.

In case if it is a java class just create a constructor and keep that snippet in that constructor..

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about "File Templates" https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-templates-android-studio/ this a large topic, but this is worth it.